# Parse Server Get all users within 1km

Tags: flutter, dart, parse-platform

I am writing a Flutter app, using Parse as the backend.
I want to get all users within 1km of a given point. For right now, I am using the default point that is used whenever I ask the simulator for the users location:

`latitude: 37.4219983, longitude: -122.084`

But whenever I inspect the result of the query, it is null.
I have several users who all have a location of  `latitude: 37.4219983, longitude: -122.084`, so I would expect it to come back with a list of those users.

```
 RaisedButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          var queryBuilder = QueryBuilder<ParseObject>(ParseObject('User'))..whereWithinKilometers('geolocation', ParseGeoPoint(latitude: 37.4219983, longitude: -122.084), 1.0);
          var res = await queryBuilder.query();
          print(res.results);
        },
        child: Text('Run Query'),
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't exactly clear or documented, but instead of using `ParseObject('User')`, you need to use `ParseUser.forQuery()`, like so:

```
 var gp = ParseGeoPoint(latitude: 37.4219983, longitude: -122.084);
 var someUsers = QueryBuilder<ParseUser>(ParseUser.forQuery())..whereWithinKilometers('geolocation', gp, 1.0);
 var res = await someUsers.query();
```